# Как спрятать уголок?

Tags: css

Привет! Как можно спрятать уголок с помощью css?

Вот так должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на песочницу: https://jsfiddle.net/drtvader/Lxnsxhef/

```
<span class="b-file__icon">PDF</span>

.b-file__icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 37px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4);
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 24px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.b-file__icon:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
.b-file__icon:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #969696;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: разбейте на три части: большой нижний прямоугольник, маленький прямоугольнике слева вверху и треугольник справа.

Comment: Можно добавить ещё один треугольник с цветом фона, в том месте где это нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background:#999;
  position:relative;
}
div:after{
  content:"";
  border:20px solid transparent;
  border-left:20px solid #fff;
  position:absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
 div:before{
  content:"";
  border:20px solid transparent;
  border-left:20px solid #dd9955;
  position:absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 9px;
  transform: rotate(134deg);
  z-index: 100;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

вот так